# KeyGesture not accepting a Shift+Alphanumeric key combination

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, keystroke

I'm attempting to execute some WPF commands with help of WPF `KeyGesture` class. Application works fine until I specify a key combination consisting of <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier and an alphanumeric key. For example, following instantiation: `new KeyGesture(Key.M, ModifierKeys.Shift)` throws an exception:

> **'Shift+M' key and modifier combination is not supported for KeyGesture.**

Bare <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier won't work with numbers too (e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>). However, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> combinations work flawlessly. Just to put it clear, there are no problems with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> and alike.

Why was a decision made to forbid <kbd>Shift</kbd> + [Alphanumeric] gesture? Does it have anything in common with typing capital letters? Is there a workaround coherent with the WPF commanding system?
(*Note: I'm not trying to use a <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> gesture, while filling textboxes, but rather when **no** textbox is in focus.*)

I seem to find only one forum entry, where this issue is raised. A documentation search failed. Is it so obvious for developers to avoid <kbd>Shift</kbd> + [Alphanumeric]?

Comment: What the hell? WHY? I've just hit this problem head on. Trouble is, I'm trying to replicate functionality in a legacy (read: money making) application.

Comment: @lainMH: Well, my knowledge on the problem hasn't changed from the time I posted this question. I believe it is because it would conflict with text insertion in most applications. You could handle Shift+key combinations at window level. But I think a better solution is just to avoid Shift+key gestures, because it'd work only in particular cases. If a textbox had focus, the keystroke is supposed to be treated as character input only. So your commands bound to Shift+key would work from time to time, driving your customer mad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See SO 8251043 - basically it's no longer a "gesture" its a keybinding
[Create a simple, unmodified key binding in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251043/create-a-simple-unmodified-key-binding-in-wpf)

Comment: It works, thank you. What a shame, it didn't appear to be documented anywhere. As an additional note - Key and Modifiers must be set through property assignment (as shown in the quoted SO 8251043) and *not* passed to the constructor. In the latter case, it's converted to a `KeyGesture` and fails.