# Create a simple, unmodified key binding in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I'm trying to create a very simple WPF application.  I'd like to have an command handler called when the user presses "H" (not Control-H or Alt-H, just H).  If I use the following in code-behind code:

```
var gesture = new KeyGesture(Key.H, ModifierKeys.None);
var inputBinding = new InputBinding(MyRoutedCommand, gesture);
InputBindings.Add(inputBinding);
```

I immediately get an exception saying that the key and modifier combination isn't supported for KeyGesture.

(I get the same exception if I create the XAML to do the analogous thing).

My application doesn't accept typed input, no text boxes are in the application, so there isn't really a conflict with text (at least in my mind).  I wouldn't have thought that this would be so unusual.

I've seen comments elsewhere that suggest that I could create a custom control for this or intercept keyboard presses at a low level, but these seem like a lot of overhead.  Any simpler thoughts?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Don't use the `KeyGesture` type or property (as one key is not a gesture).

e.g.

```
KeyBinding b = new KeyBinding()
    {
        Command = MyRoutedCommand,
        Key = Key.H
    };
InputBindings.Add(b);
```

Same for XAML

```
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding MyRoutedCommand}" Key="H" />
```

Comment: This does not work for me at all. It still gives the same error.

Comment: @Daniel: Using an old .NET version perchance?

Comment: @H.B.: I'm using .NET Framework 4.0 and compiling with Visual Studio 2010. I ended up just adding a KeyDown event to the window and checking for the particular key that was pressed.

Comment: This won't work either, because the key+modifiers validation is also triggered.