# Programmatically create a key binding for textbox input

Tags: c#, wpf, key-bindings

While searching this site, I've found this post [Create a simple, unmodified key binding in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251043/create-a-simple-unmodified-key-binding-in-wpf) which shows how to bind a simple command to the a key. However I require a bit more than this. I'd like to also set a parameter to this command. A parameter which is will be bound to a text box, I use for input.
Here's the code I have:

```
var textBinding = new Binding("Text") { Source = textBoxInput };
            buttonConfirmAddKitType.SetBinding(ButtonBase.CommandParameterProperty, textBinding);
            var keybinding = new KeyBinding
                                        {
                                            Key = Key.Enter,
                                            Command = command,
                                        };
            //Here I need a way to set the source of the command to the text of the input textbox, as done above
            textBoxInput.InputBindings.Add(keybinding);
```

The only missing piece here is how to bind the parameter of the key binding's command to the text of my textbox, and I cant seem to find the answer anywhere. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var textBinding = new Binding("Text") { Source = textBoxInput };
        buttonConfirmAddKitType.SetBinding(ButtonBase.CommandParameterProperty, textBinding);
        var keybinding = new KeyBinding
        {
            Key = Key.Enter,
            Command = command,
        };
        keybinding.CommandParameter = textBoxInput.Text;
        textBoxInput.InputBindings.Add(keybinding);
```