# Custom hotkey in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I implemented some hotkeys in my WPF application.

XAML:

```
    <KeyBinding
        Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"
        Modifiers="Control"
        Key="K"/>
```

Now I want a function where I can set custom hotkeys, so that the user can set the key individually, over a button or something similar.

Does anyone have a idea how this could be done in wpf?

Comment: See [Programmatically create a key binding for textbox input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306484/programmatically-create-a-key-binding-for-textbox-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind Key with property in view model using

```
//ViewModel
string SomeCommnadShortcut {get; set} 

<!-- xaml -->
    <KeyBinding
            Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"
            Modifiers="Control"
            Key={Binding SomeCommnadShortcut}/>
```

Then write logic that validate string, change these property and send event for update.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind Key in your ViewModel

```
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" Modifiers="Control" Key="{Binding SomeHotKey}"/>
```

Then In your ViewModel.cs:

```
private Key _SomeHotKey = System.Windows.Input.Key.K;  //Default Hotkey
public Key SomeHotKey
{
 get{ return _SomeHotKey; }
 set{ _SomeHotKey = value; }
}
```

Now, you can customize your hotkey using SomeHotKey property.