# Create a simple, unmodified key binding in WPF (.net core 3.1 /.net 5)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, inputbinding

This is an old issue, which was already asked here ([Create a simple, unmodified key binding in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251043/create-a-simple-unmodified-key-binding-in-wpf)) but the answer will not work for me. I still have a problem.

I use .net core 3.1 with WPF and I want to define a `KeyBinding` to an unmodified key by code.

In XAML

```
<Window.InputBindings>
   <KeyBinding Command="{Binding MyRoutedCommand}" Key="H" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

it works like a charm. But if I try to define the `KeyBinding` in code,

```
KeyBinding b = new KeyBinding()
{
   Command = MyRoutedCommand,
   Key = Key.H
};
InputBindings.Add(b);
```

I get a "NotSupported" exception for the gesture `None+H` directly on starting the App.

Original exception (german, Visual Studio 2019):

```
NotSupportedException: Die Kombination aus Taste und Modifizierer "None+H" wird für KeyGesture nicht unterstützt.
```

Does anybody know a reason, why XAML is working and setting the `InputBinding` by code fails?

Kind regards,
Christof

PS:

Based on some comments I found following code line in the code behind constructor.

```
  InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(MyRoutedCommand, Key.H, ModifierKeys.None));
```

If I remove this line, the exception is gone. So I think the reason for the exception is found.

**Solution (added on 2020-08-09):**

The code I mentioned in the question originaly was right. Only the line I found in the code behind file was the reason for the exception. If you compare the code lines you see, that there are two different `KeyBinding` constructors are used.

The problem is, that the parameterless `KeyBinging()` constructor and the `KeyBinding(key, modifier)` constructor work in a different way.

The constructor with key and modifier parameter will create a `KeyGesture` internally. And the KeyGesture will throw the exception if you try to use a "printable" key without a modifier key. Even the shift key is not supported by the KeyGesture. So `None + H` and `Shift + H` are not valid.

But in the KeyBinding class itself, it is no problem to use these key combinations. If you need to define a KeyBinding to a "printable" key, just use the parameterless KeyBiding constructor and add the RoutedCommand and the key manually before you add the KeyBinding to the InputBindings. This is shown in the code above.

I have to say "Thank you" for the comments. Without the help I wouldn't have seen my mistake in the code behind file.

Comment: Can you post full message of NotSupported Exception?

Comment: original exception text added to question

Comment: So when they press H anywhere in the entire window, you wish to invoke a command? Including text in Textboxes?

Comment: How is the routedcommand itself set up?

Comment: @Andy correct! But we have no textBoxes in the window. There is only a ViewPort3D control. And by pressing a key (H) I want to invoke a command.

Comment: @ChristofK Please do a quick search in your solution if you have used `KeyGesture` anywhere in code-behind.

Comment: `public static RoutedCommand MyRoutedCommand { get { return backingField; } }`
 
`private static RoutedCommand backingField = new RoutedCommand();`

Comment: @thatguy I found this additional code in the code behind constructor of the window 
`InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(MyRoutedCommand, Key.H, ModifierKeys.None));` but no KeyGesture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NotSupportedException: Die Kombination aus Taste und Modifizierer "None+H" wird für KeyGesture nicht unterstützt.

Both of your solutions work for .NET Framework, as well as .NET Core 3.1. This exception is clearly about `KeyGesture`. You instantiate a `KeyGesture` with a `None` modifier like below when creating the key binding and that will throw the `NotSupportedException`. Removing this line or assigning a modifier will resolve it.

```
InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(MyRoutedCommand, Key.H, ModifierKeys.None));
```

As a [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keygesture.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Input_KeyGesture__ctor_System_Windows_Input_Key_) from MSDN about `KeyGesture` and modifier keys:

> In most cases, a KeyGesture **must** be associated with one or more ModifierKeys. The exceptions to this rule are the function keys and the numeric keypad keys, which can be a valid KeyGesture by themselves.

Comment: OK, I see. But why the XAML code '<Window.InputBindings>
   <KeyBinding Command="{Binding MyRoutedCommand}" Key="H" />
</Window.InputBindings>' is working correctly? 

Is this not the same?

Comment: @ChristofK. No, the XAML code that you have posted is equivalent to the `KeyBinding` in your question, but **not** to `new KeyBinding(MyRoutedCommand, Key.H, ModifierKeys.None)`.

Comment: Thanks! That was my missing link!